# AjaxToolKit Extensions not showing up once published to WebServer

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I've run into an issue today that I can't seem to figure out. I am currently using AjaxToolKit MaskEditExtension and CalendarExtension. Everything works great on my development machine but once I publish the site to the Webserver (Server 2008 IIS7) neither of the extensions are displayed. I have searched the web for a few hours trying different things but nothing as worked. I have found that "all you needed to add" was..

add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

but this did not solve my problem. I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012. Any help is appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out finally. Had to put this in my code behind to see which version of the framework I was using exactly..

Response.Write("Version: " + System.Environment.Version.ToString());

This then showed that I was using 4.0.30319.18047.

I then went in inserted this..

```
<add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.30319.18047, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

with the framework version that I found I was using. Published and now it works!

Comment: <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.30319.18047, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /> Sorry, it didn't show this in the answer for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the assemblies were published along with your project.  In the References folder of your project, right-click on AjaxControlToolkit, select Properties and make sure Copy Local is set to True.  This will make sure the assembly is included in your project's /bin folder when you build/publish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already set the "Copy Local" to true. I have tried multiple things including deleting the AjaxToolkit from the bin folder on the web server and copying the one from my local bin folder. That didn't work either. I found a few things when researching this problem but none of those worked either. I'm not too sure what to do.

Comment: Is there anything else I can try to do? I'm still having problems. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the app pool you are publishing to and your project are both targeting the same version of .NET.  I just noticed the config code you posted in your question had "Version" set to 3.5.0.0 but your question was tagged c#-4.0.  You could also try setting the version in your config code to 4.0.0.0.  Basically just make sure everything is targeting the same version, including the .dll files you are referencing.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to put that piece of code back into it. I saw that online I should use that but I will give it a try with the 4.0.0.0. I think I did once already but it was a few days ago, so I'm not positive anymore. Thanks again!

Comment: I have tried the 4.0.0.0. Since I'm developing in vs 2012, I even tried the 4.5.0.0 since projects created in  vs 2012 use the 4.5 framework. This did not work either.

Comment: All the newest framework has been downloaded on the server and on my local machine. They are both .net 4.5 and I uninstalled the AjaxToolkit version 4.0 and re-installed the AjaxToolkit 4.5. Using the AjaxToolkit.dll from the new 4.5. Set that .dll to copy local. Verified that it is copied to the server. It still is not displaying. I have searched and searched for an answer with no results.